# how to change country code in firebaseUI auth web

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-authentication

I trigger the firebaseUI phone  number authentication on a button click. How to bind the country code (which user has selected in the field country in the form, i.e when user has selected the country i want that country to be displayed/bind it in firebaseUI phone number auth dialog)

Answer (score 10):

Refer to the documentation for configuring phone auth with FirebaseUI: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-phone-provider

You have the ability to set the default selected country via `defaultCountry` configuration field, eg:

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      // The default selected country.
      defaultCountry: 'GB'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Not the default. I meant, I want to bind other text input country code with firebase country code. Like, say i have 2 inputs and a save button. User chooses the country code and hits save button and then the firebase phone auth popup is called. So, I want to bind the added country code to firebase country code.